# Plot Specific Column Values With Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a .csv for which I am able to plot a bar chart which shows all of the values within one column called "Likely Cause", the problem is there's too many of them.I want to be able to plot a subset of the values i.e. there are roughly 60 different "Likely Causes" I want to plot the count for 10 of them

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

# specify file
file = r"XXX"

# Ignore rows 0 & 1 and use row 2 as the header row
#Loaded via column number range 0-6 as column 7 had values that Python struggled with. 

data = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=[0, 1], header=0, usecols=range(0,7))  

#plots all values by count on one chart. I just want a subset
data['Likely Cause'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh')

plt.show()
```

Comment: out of the 60, how do you pick only 10?

Comment: I've used different code to list out all of the values and the count for how many times each value occurs - so I know the names of each value and which are relevant.